# What does 'ANGLORUM REGIS QUI COR LEONIS DICTUS' mean?

Tags: medieval-latin, inscription

In the cathedral of Rouen I visited the grave of Richard I the Lionheart. It has an inscription:

[image: Richard the Lionheart]

> ANGLORVM REGIS QVI COR LEONIS DICTVS

So what is the best translation?

- King of England, who ruled with a lion heart?
- English King, who ruled with a lion heart?
- Maybe something else?

Comment: Note that the line you quoted in the title, and in the question, does not stand alone, so it's not possible to say just what "ANGLORVM REGIS QVI COR LEONIS DICTVS" means. It's not grammatically valid without the preceding line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Here is interred the heart of Richard, King of the English, called Lionheart. Died in the year 1199."

Comment: Do note that the inscription has "Anglorum" (of the English), not "angelorum" (of the angels).

Comment: @fdb You evoke the shade of Gregory the Great : _non angli, sed angeli!_

Comment: Note that this is the translation of the whole inscription, not just the part quoted in the question.